# como solucionar Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente cogido para realizar una consulta de `insert` pero a la hora de enviar el formulario me aparece el mensaje de :

> Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in
>   C:\xampp_7_3_4\htdocs\Control_flotilla\scripts\reg_vehiculo.php on
>   line 20

Problemas al insertar.

A que se debe como lo podría solucionar??

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","controldeflotilla") or die (mysqli_error());
//id inputs
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$marca=$_POST['marca'];
$modelo=$_POST['modelo'];
$año=$_POST['año'];
$placa=$_POST['placa'];
$tipo=$_POST['tipo'];
$fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
$departamento=$_POST['departamento'];
$empresa=$_POST['empresa'];
$asignado=$_POST['asignado'];
$rendimiento=$_POST['rendimiento'];
$serie=$_POST['serie'];
$nombre_gasolina=$_POST['nombre_gasolina'];

$insertar="INSERT INTO vehiculo(vehiculo, marca, modelo, año, placa, tipo de vehiculo, fecha de renovacion, departamento, empresa, asignado, redimiento,no serie , nombre actual carga de gasolina) VALUES ('$nombre','$marca','$modelo','$año','$placa','$tipo','$fecha','$departamento','$empresa','$asignado','$rendimiento','$serie','$nombre_gasolina')";

mysqli_query($con,$insertar) or die ("Problemas al insertar".mysqli_error());

echo "Registro Exitoso";

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: falta indicarle de que conexión traer los errores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error dice:

> mysqli_error() espera exactamente 1 parametro, 0 dados en ...

La forma correcta seria asi:

```
mysqli_query($con,$insertar) or die ("Problemas al insertar".mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: ya puse como me indicas pero ahora salio esto:

Comment: Problemas al insertarYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '�o, placa, tipo de vehiculo, fecha de renovacion, departamento, empresa, asigna' at line 1

Comment: Ese es un error diferente, probablemente por la `ñ` que tienes en `año`.