# PHP Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in

Tags: php

Tengo este archivo PHP que funcionaba correctamente en un servidor con PHP5, luego al migrar a un vps con PHP7 tuve que corregir algunos códigos que estaban obsoletos y ahora me salta ese error.
En realidad no se de PHP, la persona que realizó éste proyecto fue difícil de ubicar para realizar los cambios y actualizar algunas cosas, así que me puse a hacerlo yo mismo mirando algunos tutoriales y logré realizar la conexión a la base de datos y otras cosas más, pero en este archivo tengo algunos problemas, alguna sugerencia de como podría solucionarlo?

```
    <?php
require('pdf/fpdf.php');

function fsalida($cad2){
$tres=substr($cad2, 0, 4);
$dos= nombreMes(substr($cad2, 5, 2));
$uno=substr($cad2, 8, 2);
$cad = ($uno." de ".$dos." de ".$tres);
return $cad;
}
function nombreMes ($mes)
{$meses = array ("enero", "febrero", "marzo", "abril", "mayo",
                "junio", "julio", "agosto", "septiembre",
                "octubre", "noviembre", "diciembre");
$i=0;
$enc=false;
while ($i<12 and !$enc)
{if ($i == $mes-1)
    $enc = true;
 else
    $i++;
 }
 return ($meses[$i]);
 }


  $fecha = date ("Y-m-d");
  $pdf=new FPDF('L','mm','A4');
  $pdf->AddPage();
  $pdf->SetRightMargin(5); 
  $mysqli = mysqli_connect("host","usuario","contraseña","nombre_bd") or 
  die 
  ("No se puede seleccionar base de datos.");

  $instruccion = "SELECT h1st0_r3g_t4bl.codigot, h1st0_r3g_t4bl.dni_registrador, usu_4r10s.nombres, 
  usu_4r10s.apellidos, h1st0_r3g_t4bl.dni_registrado, h1st0_r3g_t4bl.fechareg FROM h1st0_r3g_t4bl, 
  usu_4r10s 
  where h1st0_r3g_t4bl.dni_registrador = usu_4r10s.dni ";


  $consulta = mysqli_query ($instruccion) or die ("Fallo en la consulta 25". mysqli_errno().":". 
  mysqli_error());
  $n= mysqli_num_rows ($consulta);
  if ($n > 0)
  {   $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);

  $pdf->Cell(100,85,$pdf->Image('./imagenes/Logo.jpg',30,30,30),0,0,'C');
  $pdf->Ln(15);
  $pdf->Cell(280,20,' ',0,1,'C');
  $pdf->Cell(280,3,'INFORME HISTORIAL REGISTRADOS',0,1,'C');
  $pdf->Cell(60,5,'',0,1,'C');
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
  $pdf->Cell(190,8,'',0,0,'C');
  $pdf->Cell(90,10,"Fecha de Impresion: ".fsalida($fecha),0,1,'C');
  $pdf->Ln(); 
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',11);
  $pdf->Cell(30,7,'TABLA',1,0,'C');
  $pdf->Cell(40,7,'DNI REGISTRADOR',1,0,'C');
  $pdf->Cell(60,7,'NOMBRES REGISTRADOR',1,0,'C');
  $pdf->Cell(60,7,'APELLIDOS REGISTRADOR',1,0,'C');
  $pdf->Cell(36,7,'DNI REGISTRADO',1,0,'C');
  $pdf->Cell(30,7,'REGISTRO',1,0,'C');


  $pdf->Ln();
   for ($i=0; $i<$n; ++$i)
   {  $row = mysql_fetch_array($consulta);
      $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
      $pdf->Cell(30,7,$row['codigot'],1,0,'C');
      $pdf->Cell(40,7,$row['dni_registrador'],1,0,'C');
      $pdf->Cell(60,7,$row['nombres'],1,0,'C');
      $pdf->Cell(60,7,$row['apellidos'],1,0,'C');
      $pdf->Cell(36,7,$row['dni_registrado'],1,0,'C');
       $pdf->Cell(30,7,$row['fechareg'],1,0,'C');
      $pdf->Ln(); 



  }

      $pdf->Ln();
      $pdf->Ln();
  }

 else
 {
 $pdf->Cell(60,25,'',0,1,'C');
 $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
 $pdf->Cell(60,10,'',0,1,'C');
 $pdf->Cell(60);
 $pdf->Cell(60,5,'NO HAY DATOS PROCESADOS EN ESTE MOMENTO',0,1,'C');


  }

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Lamentablemente me muestra el siguiente error:

PHP Warning:  mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in line 40

Answer (score 0):

Te falta indicar a qué base de datos se conecta.

`mysqli_connect(...)` te regresa una liga (*link*) a la base de datos, yo normalmente lo dejo en la variable `$db`:

```
$db = mysql_connect(...); // Ponle los parámetros de conexión
```

Después, cualqueir cosa que hagas sobre esa base, tienes que decírselo a PHP, de hecho tu `mysqli_query()` no debería funcionar, ya que lo deberías llamar con:

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

Seguro que eso está generando el `mysqli_error()`, al que también le debes pasar la conexión:

```
mysqli_error($db)
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

El error te esta diciendo lo que debes hacer.

> mysqli_error() esperaba 1 parametro, 0 recibidos

la forma correcta es en tu `mysqli_error()` pasarle tu variable de conexion.

```
$consulta = mysqli_query ($instruccion) or die ("Fallo en la consulta 25". mysqli_errno().":". mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

Te sugiero que no lo hagas de esa manera, es inseguro y se puede romper facilmente, podrias hacerlo con queries preparadas.

Link original de la respuesta [como solucionar Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/259468/como-solucionar-warning-mysqli-error-expects-exactly-1-parameter-0-given-in)

Comment: Gracias, me ayudó bastante

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer tienes varios errores, tú función `mysqli_query ($mysqli,$instruccion)` debe llevar dos parámetros y tu método: `mysqli_error($mysqli)` debe llevar la instancia de la conexión o sea `$mysqli`

Prueba esto:

```
 $mysqli = mysqli_connect("host","usuario","contraseña","nombre_bd") or 
  die 
  ("No se puede seleccionar base de datos.");

  $instruccion = "SELECT h1st0_r3g_t4bl.codigot, h1st0_r3g_t4bl.dni_registrador, usu_4r10s.nombres, 
  usu_4r10s.apellidos, h1st0_r3g_t4bl.dni_registrado, h1st0_r3g_t4bl.fechareg FROM h1st0_r3g_t4bl, 
  usu_4r10s 
  where h1st0_r3g_t4bl.dni_registrador = usu_4r10s.dni ";


  $consulta = mysqli_query ($mysqli,$instruccion) or die ("Fallo en la consulta 25". mysqli_errno().":". 
  mysqli_error($mysqli));
  $n= mysqli_num_rows ($consulta);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, pude resolverlo.